# Airtag not updating its position even during a trip on a road full of cars and with my iPhone nearby

Tags: airtag

I have purchased this AirTag one year ago.

At the beginning, it was working fine.

Now what happens is this: it takes hours to report the correct location. I know it depends on finding an iPhone nearby to transmit its position but consider this situation.

I have it in my car. Not only that, but I have my iPhone in my pocket, supposedly communicating with the AirTag. I do a two-hour drive. The road is full of cars. The AirTag was supposed to use my iPhone, during the drive, to communicate its position, right?

I arrive at the destination.

Two hours later, I check, and it is showing its position as being in a point I was after one hour of driving. A road which has tons of cars all the time.

I suppose it is malfunctioning, right?

At least the time my iPhone was nearby, it should be using it to communicate its position, right?

1. Yes, I have replaced the battery.
2. Yes, I also have removed it and paired it again.
3. Yes, I did reset the settings on this iPhone.
4. The AirTag will use my iPhone the time I am nearby, right?
5. How frequent AirTags ping their position?
6. Every so often it takes 2 days to show the correct position.
7. I have compared the reported position on FindMy on iPhone, iPad, and macOS and the iPhone reports another position entirely different!!!!!!!!!!! The iPhone shows a localization near the destination!

Its firmware is version 2.0.61.

thanks